# encoding issue when reading CSV file with python

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I have hit a road block when trying to read a CSV file with python.

UPDATE:
if you want to just skip the character or error you can open the file like this:

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as data_file:
```

So far I have tried.

```
for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r') as data_file:
            reader = csv.reader(data_file)
            for row in reader:
                print (row)
```

the error I am getting is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 224-225: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have Tried

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as data_file:
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 223: character maps to <undefined>
```

Now if I just print the data_file it says they are cp1252 encoded but if I try

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r', encoding="cp1252") as data_file:
```

The error I get is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 224-225: character maps to <undefined>
```

I also tried the recommended package.

The error I get is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 224-225: character maps to <undefined>
```

The line I am trying to parse is:

```
2015-11-28 22:23:58,670805374291832832,479174464,"MarkCrawford15","RT @WhatTheFFacts: The tallest man in the world was Robert Pershing Wadlow of Alton, Illinois. He was slighty over 8 feet 11 inches tall.","None
```

any thoughts or help is appreciated.

Comment: cp1252, according to google, is a windows character encoding. What's your environment and where did the files come from? If you open the csv file in nano, for instance, does it say that it's in dos format?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by open file in nano... I am on a windows machine.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you might be on unix - I've had trouble parsing DOS formatted files on linux before and thought it may have been a similar issue. Nano is an in terminal text editor common on linux systems.

Comment: try `for row in reader: data = [unicode(i,'utf-8') for i in row] print data`

Comment: I just tried it I am getting the error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 127: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/), that uses automatic detection of apposite encoding and decoding. e.g.

```
import csvkit
reader = csvkit.reader(data_file)
```

As disscussed in the chat- solution is-

```
for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root_dir): 
    for file in files: 
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as data_file: 
            reader = csv.reader(data_file) 
            for row in reader: 
                data = [i.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii') for i in row] 
                print (data)
```

Comment: thanks man I dont have the ability to install packages in my environment currently

Comment: Have you come across miniconda? It doesn't require admin privileges to use.

Comment: `for row in reader:
   data = [i.encode('utf-8') for i in row]
    print data`

Comment: Could you post the content of `row`

Comment: ya so its really weird the row when I open with excel or a text editor has no issues and is 
2015-11-28 07:32:32,670581036858933248,3256765652

but from looking at the error it looks like there is just a character that doesnt exist

Comment: is there a way to just skip that character if its not able to be decoded?

Comment: Ah! Strange . could you attach sample dummy file whereas i can test?

Comment: ya ill see what I can do and to add to it I just got on a different device and was able to try your package out and I got the same error!!! lol ok stand by for update to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96820/discussion-between-sislam-and-user3271518).